# How to connect to the WebAPI which is hosted on N3 network machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, visual-studio-2022

How to connect to the WebAPI which is hosted on N3 network machine? In detail:

1. We have a machine which is connected to the N3 network (N3 is a national broadband network for the English National Health Service (NHS), connecting all NHS locations and 1.3 million employees across England).
2. I have created a API which can access patient data from NHS and everything is working fine.
3. Once we deploy this API on our server (which is not connected to N3 network and cant be connected to N3) API cant be accessed outside this machine.

can you please suggest/advice alternatives to access this API which is on a machine which is connected to N3 and the IP is not accessed outside the network.

I tried to deploy the API on the machine (which has access to N3 network as mentioned in point 1) and hosted on IIS to access it outside the network. As this machine IP not allowed for public so cant access the API.

Comment: Hello, if the IP address cannot be disclosed due to some reasons, then you can use the reverse proxy method. It is equivalent to adding a server between the machine and the network. Forward requests from the machine to the website.

Comment: Never used reverse proxy..will give it a read and try. Thanks